# How to make a windows shortcut to open a specific project?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm evaluating PHPStorm, but I have several different projects.

It seems PHPStorm can only open 1 project in a window?

How can I create different Windows shortcuts to specify the project that PHPStorm opens with?

In Eclipse I can specify the workspace that should be opened, is there an equivalent for this in PHPStorm ?

Comment: Shortcut: normal shortcut to PhpStorm executable and then add **full path to the folder** where `.idea` subfolder (your project settings) is located as a parameter, e.g. `path\to\phpstorm.exe C:\project\myproject.co.uk`

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is creating separate shortcuts for each project. In the shortcuts target put:

```
"C:\<phpStorm_path>\PhpStorm.exe" C:\project\project-directory
```

Also note that this is related to webStorm as well.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, you can create a shortcut that points to the exe followed by your project. In addition, beyond just adding one project, you can add multiple projects, and they all open when you open that shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 10.0\bin\WebStorm64.exe" "D:\code\proj_server" "D:\code\proj_client"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for

> File > New Project from existing files

If you then try to open another project

> File > Open Recent

PhpStorm will ask you if you want to open it in this window or new window

Comment: Sometimes opening last open project (with indexing and version control refresh all over NFS) takes to long -- my PHPStorm is unresponsive, I can't switch to the project of my choice until background jobs quiet down.

Comment: @MihaiStancu you can change that behavior via Settings > IDE Settings > General > Reopen last project on startup.